# arm neon vst1.32 segfault

Tags: assembly, arm, inline-assembly, neon

The following code simply tries to copy the data from the 'in*' arrays to the 'out*' arrays, but segfaults at the first `vst1.32` instruction, but why?

```
int* in0 = new int[4]{ 0x0, 0x1, 0x2, 0x3 };
int* in1 = new int[4]{ 0x4, 0x5, 0x6, 0x7 };
int* in2 = new int[4]{ 0x8, 0x9, 0xA, 0xB };
int* in3 = new int[4]{ 0xC, 0xD, 0xE, 0xF };

int* out0 = new int[4]{};
int* out1 = new int[4]{};
int* out2 = new int[4]{};
int* out3 = new int[4]{};

asm volatile("vld1.32 {d0, d1}, [%[in0]]      \n"
             "vld1.32 {d2, d3}, [%[in1]]      \n"
             "vld1.32 {d4, d5}, [%[in2]]      \n"
             "vld1.32 {d6, d7}, [%[in3]]      \n"
             "vst1.32 {d0, d1}, [%[out0]]     \n"
             "vst1.32 {d2, d3}, [%[out1]]     \n"
             "vst1.32 {d4, d5}, [%[out2]]     \n"
             "vst1.32 {d6, d7}, [%[out3]]     \n"
             : [out0]"=r"(out0), [out1]"=r"(out1), [out2]"=r"(out2), [out3]"=r"(out3)
             : [in0]"r"(in0), [in1]"r"(in1), [in2]"r"(in2), [in3]"r"(in3)
             : "d0", "d1", "d2", "d3", "d4", "d5", "d6", "d7", "memory", "cc"
             );
```

Comment: http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0491f/BABDCGGF.html is watermarked as "superseded". Maybe you should look for what superseded this command.

Comment: using the search feature produced this page: http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0491f/BABDCGGF.html - So I think it may actually that _version_ of the documentation as a whole that has been superseded, and not the individual instruction.

Comment: `[out0]"=r"(out0)` means that the value in out0 will be overwritten by the asm.  And since the value is never used before it gets overwritten, what's the point of assigning something to it?  IOW, as counter-intuitive as it seems, out0 is an input.  So how do you tell gcc that you are modifying the *contents* of out0?  In this case, the memory clobber should suffice.

Comment: @DavidWohlferd Thanks! it works now. If you post answer, I will accept.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`[out0]"=r"(out0)` means that the value in out0 will be overwritten by the asm. And since the value is never used before it gets overwritten, what's the point of assigning something to it?

In other words, as counter-intuitive as it seems, out0 is an input.

So how do you tell gcc that you are modifying the *contents* of out0? In this case, the memory clobber should suffice.